# simple ng-expression not working

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

For validation in an Angular app, I'm trying to ensure the input value ends with the string "ism", so I'm using

```
ng-pattern="\b\w+(ism\b)"
```

This isn't triggering $invalid for the input when the expression isn't matched, however, and neither is

```
ng-pattern="ism$".
```

I'm getting an error message in the console, which seems to be saying it doesn't like the expression(s) as typed:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/lexerrp0=Unexpected  
%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%200-0%20%5B%5C%5D&p2=%5Cb%5Cw%2B(ism%5Cb)...
```

Comment: Please add enough of your code to the question to allow reproduction of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can understand you need something like this `ng-pattern="/ism$/"`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evf4sxfh/)

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type="text" name="test" ng-model="test" ng-pattern="/ism$/" />
    <span ng-show="myform.test.$error.pattern">Not valid pattern!</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Michelem, that was it. To clarify the answer for others, I didn't realize the starting and ending forward slashes are required in the ng-pattern value, that was the problem. I ended up using ng-pattern="/.*ism$/", but "/\b\w+(ism\b)/" works just as well, as does "/ism$/".

The forward slashes aren't needed if one specifies the ng-pattern value as a RegExp object, e.g., ng-pattern="new RegExp('.*ism$')". It's probably better to put that RegExp into a $scope variable, if it's going to be used more than once.